# Limit of imaginary part divided by real part of an entire function on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits, harmonic-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. I assume that the $lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{\Im(f(z))}{\Re(f(z))}$ should be bounded. But is this the case, and if yes, how can I prove it? Or could I make a statement about the $\limsup$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  Take the function $f(z)=z$ and let $z\to\infty$ along the curve
$z(t)=1/t+it$.

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac t{1/t}=\infty.$$

Comment: Hmm, I see. So does $\Re(f(z))|z|^{-a}\le K$ not imply $\Re(f(z)z^{-a})\le K$ for large $z$ ?

Comment: The limit you  wrote isn't right, but  the idea works.

Comment: Oops I'll fix it.

Comment: $z(t)=1/t+it$ would work, right?

Comment: @QuirinVo Yes, and that is exactly what I changed my example to.

Comment: Would you be so kind and give me a hint how to approach the problem I asked in my first comment? :) Thank you

Comment: Let me think about that for a bit.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski thank you, just let you know that those $K$'s do not have to be idenitcal, just both finite

Comment: Is $\alpha$ real?

Comment: yes, my bad, real and positive

Comment: Well then it's trivally true, if $a\in\Bbb R$ and $z\in\Bbb C$ then $\Re(az)=a\Re(z)$.

Comment: but we dont have that, we have $\Re (f(z)z^{-a})$ which is $\Re(f(z))\Re(z^{-a})-\Im(f(z))\Im(z^{-a})$ @TimRaczkowski

Comment: sorry misread it

Comment: Are we talking about $|\text {Re}f(z)|\,|z|^{-\alpha}$ or $\text {Re}f(z)|z|^{-\alpha}$?

Comment: $\Re f(z)|z|^{-a}$ @zhw.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this always fails (unless $f$ is constant): If $f$ is entire and nonconstant, then there exists a sequnce $z_n \to \infty$ such that

$$(1)\,\,\,\,\frac{\text {Im} \,f(z_n)}{\text {Re}\, f(z_n)} \to \infty.$$

Proof: $f(\{|z|>R\})$ is dense in $\mathbb {C}$ for each $R>0.$ Thus, for each $n\in \mathbb {N}$ there is $z_n, |z_n|>n$ such that $f(z_n)\in D(1+ni,1).$ It follows that $\text {Im}\,f(z_n) > n - 1,0< \text {Re}\,f(z_n) < 2.$ This gives (1).

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I was looking for an easy solution to my problem stated in the first comment, so I was wishing for it to be true :D